# Makefile compiling the good files without the dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, dependencies

I have a problem with the dependencies in my Makefile.
There is no problem with the compilation, it compiles perfectly the good *.cc and *.hh but unfortunately, it does not re-compile the dependencies, thus there is no update in the executable.

Here is my makefile:

```
EXEC      ?= program

SRCS      = $(shell find -name *.cc)
DEP       = $(SRCS:.cc=.d)

OBJDIR    = objs
OBJS     = $(SRCS:./%.cc=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

CXX       = g++
CFLAGS    = -std=c++14 $(addprefix "-I", $(shell find -type d))

## Clean rule
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
    rm -f $(EXEC)

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
    @echo "Linking: $@"
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $@

-include $(DEP)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : ./%.cc ./%.hh
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo "Compiling: $<"
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -o $@ $<
```

It is probably something related to the flag used by `g++` but I do not manage to find the solution;
Thanks in advance for the help that you can provide on this issue,

Comment: You have `DEP` as a function of `CSRC` -- I presume it should actually be `SRCS`?

Comment: Yep sorry. I just simplified the actual Makefile and I forgot to edit this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the filename for the generated dependency files, it is going to be `${@:%.o=%.d}` (compiler logic). I.e. your dependency files are in `$(OBJDIR)` and not in `./` where your makefile expects them to be.

Two alternative solutions:

1. `DEP := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)`.
2. `@$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(<:%.cc=%.d) -o $@ $<`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I used the 1st one and it solved the problem :).